# Rotate image with its objects

Tags: android, rotation

Firstly I'm using Android application to rotating image with selected angle. that image has drawable lines by canvas.
I'm able to rotate the image but the line not.
I want to rotate and draw lines with new directions.

Comment: could you post your code ?

Comment: I'm didn't use specific code, I'm want code to explain how that doing